# YouTube Video not playing correctly after after toggling the player's visibility

Tags: javascript, flash, firefox, jquery-dialog, youtube-javascript-api

I am using [YouTube JS API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) to play videos on my site. Video is played on the dialog box. When user closes the dialog box, player is stopped - `player.stopVideo();` But when user clicks again on video icon again, dialog box appears

- In **Chrome**, the video starts playing at the previous position - **OK**
- **Firefox**, the video starts playing from the start irrespective of where user left it last time. - **NOT OK**

As per my requirements, I want the Chrome to behave as how firefox is behaving.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hH3qm/4/

Comment: Hi Rob, Thanks for the comment. Could you just send me your email and I can drop u a URL where you can click on video link on both browsers, I can also send you the code snippet.

Comment: I don't mind helping, but the purpose of Stack Overflow is that questions & answers posted here are also helpful to future visitors. Can you create a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/, to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Hi Rob, I will create a demo later in the day, but just send you a mail, if that helps.

Comment: I tried to create one online demo on jsfiddle, but could not make it work.Here is the URL- http://jsfiddle.net/hH3qm/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that the Flash player is reset when it's not visible. Firefox seems to be bugged, such that it does not return to the correct position when it starts again. To fix it, use the `player.cueTo(player.getCurrentTime())`.

Also, when the API methods are called too quickly, ie before the Flash object is ready, the `Error calling method on NPObject!` is thrown. To solve this, defer the call.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hH3qm/13/show/

```
$("#watch_video_overlay").dialog({ //dialog -jquery ui method
    width: '680',
    height: 'auto',
    modal: true,
    show: 'fade',
    hide: 'fade',
    open: function () {
        if ($.browser.mozilla) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                player.seekTo(player.getCurrentTime());
            },
            1000);
        } else {
            player.playVideo();
        }
    },
    close: function () {
        // Pause it, btw.
        player.pauseVideo();
    }
});
```